# Call a jQuery vertical align plugin using multiple selectors

Tags: jquery, html, css, margin, vertical-alignment

The idea is simple get the `height` of the *bigger-objet* (`h1`) and of the *smaller-object* (`h2`), substract them and divide over 2. In other words `h3=(h1-h2)/2`. And use said `h3` as `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` for the *smaller-object*.

From what I understood from this [reference](http://www.re-cycledair.com/creating-jquery-plugins). I came up with this:

```
(function($) {
 $.fn.vAlign = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
   var bigger_height_object = document.getElementsByClassName('object-aligned-against');
   var smaller_height_object = document.getElementsByClassName('aligned-object');
   var h1 = bigger_height_object.height();
   var h2 = smaller_height_object.height();
   var h3 = (h1-h2) / 2;
   smaller_height_object.css('margin-top', h3);
   smaller_height_object.css('margin-bottom', h3);
  });
 };
}) (jQuery);
```

From what I [read](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/), it is possible to use multiple selectors, so would it be possible to call the *plugin* as something like this: `$('.aligned-object' '.object-aligned-against').vAlign()` ?
Or what would be the appropriate way to do it?

Edit: missed the `.` on the selector classes.

Edit2: removed the `,` on the selector, since I'm looking for both of the classes independentlty.

Comment: I generally avoid using js for styling purposes.  Yes, it can work but very often it causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: On a more helpful note, it is very important to remember that `$('aligned-object', 'object-aligned-against')` is not the same as `$('aligned-object object-aligned-against')`.  In the first, you are looking for a `aligned-object` _inside_ of `object-aligned-against`.  In the second you are looking for both independently.  I don't think either suites your purpose here though.  I would recommend creating a wrapper (like a div) and passing that in instead.

Comment: @nurdyguy, how would you do it? Using CSS media queries seems like an endless job, since I have no idea of which _break points_ should I use. 2 break points seem too little for me. On my phone, and laptop it may look aligned but what about the rest of the screens? How do you test that?

Comment: I agree that media queries probably aren't the best for this.  What kind of things are you trying to vertically align?  There are a ton of tricks for creating vertical allignment, I always just google them until I find one that works.

Comment: Two `<div>`s inside the same `w3-row`, some `<div>`s have an `<img>` inside, while others have a `<p>`

Comment: Target the outer `w3-row`, something like `$('#theRow').vAlign();` then inside the package you can find the divs nested inside of it.  This way it will be properly encapsulated.  I would suggest trying something like this first though:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div?rq=1

Comment: @nurdyguy, It seems I need to define the height of the container, right? What would be a good way of defining it? Thanks, BTW, seems I was trying to do something harder than it should.